# R: Fill bar plot with text

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, frequency

I have survey data where each question has numerous different options (all encoded by a code of three letters), like so:

```
# example data
data <- data.frame(question = c(1,1,2,2,3), answer = c('CD1', 'CD2', 'CD5', 'CD1', 'CD2'), perc = c(0.25, 0.75, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0))

# simple bar plot
ggplot(data, aes(x=question, y = perc, fill = answer)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Obviously this bar plot gets messy when there are tons of codes, therefore we want to replace the bar itself by the three letter code like so (ignore the y-axis this should be something like % of total): 
[image] 
(*[example from DNA codons](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3389775/))*

This could be done when `geom_text` would support a starting y and ending y coordinate, like `x, y.start, y.end`, however as far as I know this is not possibile.

Comment: The following [answer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/347490/como-preencher-gr%c3%a1ficos-de-coluna-com-hachuras-usando-ggplot2/347529#347529) to a SO in Portuguese question might be what you are looking for. Try to see if Google Translate can sort it out for you.

Comment: hmm that package seems to draw images only, then I should make images of all three letter codes that is too cumbersome @RuiBarradas

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something you may want to try:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(question,perc,fill=answer))+geom_tile()+
  geom_text(aes(label=answer))
```

You could edit as you wish, it would make it less messed up than a bar plot.